# Modular exponentiation implementation in Python 3

Tags: python, algorithm, python-3.x, pseudocode, modular-arithmetic

Basically this is a homework question. I'm supposed to implement these two pseudo-code algorithms in Python3. I'm doing something wrong and I can't figure out what (it seems like this should be simple so I'm not sure what/where I botched this. It could be my algorithm or my lack of experience with Python. I'm not sure which.).

Please tell me what I did wrong, don't post any code. If I get code for an answer I'll get pegged for plagiarism (which I very much do not want).

The first algorithm (base expansion):

```
    procedure base expansion(n, b: positive integers with b > 1)
    q := n
    k := 0
    while q ≠ 0
        ak := q mod b
        q := q div b
        k := k + 1
    return (ak-1, ... , a1, a0) {(ak-1 ... a1 a0)b is the base b expansion of n}
```

the second algorithm (modular expansion):

```
    procedure modular exponentiation(b: integer, n = (ak-1ak-2...a1a0)2, m: positive integers)
    x := 1
    power := b mod m
    for i := 0 to k - 1
        if ai = 1 then x := (x * power) mod m
        power := (power * power) mod m
    return x {x equals bn mod m}
```

Seems simple enough anyway, here's what I implemented in Python3 (and I beg forgiveness of all Python programmers out there, this is a very new language for me)

```
def baseExp(n, b):
    q = n
    a = []
    while (q != 0):
        a.append(q % b)
        q = q // b
        pass
    return a

def modularExp(b, n, m):
    a = baseExp(n, b)
    x = 1
    power = b % m
    for i in range(0, len(a)):
        if (a[i] == 1):
            x = (x * power) % m
            pass
        power = (power * power) % m
        pass
    return x
```

This seems like it should work, but when I attempt to solve 7<sup>644</sup> mod 645 I get the answer 79 but the right answer should be 436.

If anyone could point out my mistakes without actually giving me any code I'd be extremely appreciative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method will only work if b equals 2, which is same as exponentiation by squaring but it will fail in cases with b > 2. Here's how:

Your string n can contain numbers in the range [0,b-1] as it is the representation of number n in base b. In your code, you only check for digit 1, and in the case of b = 7, there can be any digit in the range [0,6]. You have to modify your algorithm as follows :

```
// take appropriate remainders where required
// Correction 1 :
In the for loop,
Check if a[i] = 1, then x = x * power
else if a[i] = 2, then x = x * power^2
else if a[i] = 3, then x = x * power^3
.
.
.
.
till a[i] = b-1, then x = x * power^(b-1)
// Correction 2 :
After checking a[i] 
power = power^b and not power = power^2 which is only good for b = 2
```

You should now get the correct answer.

Comment: Thanks a bunch. I've been wracking my brain all week and I've been super sick. The changes you suggested make the algorithm work. What I don't get is why the pseudo-code in my book wasn't written out like the way you described (I double checked my book to make sure I didn't just mistype it here, so either I don't understand the book's notation or it was wrong). Thanks again, you were a lifesaver!

Comment: It seems like the pseudo code for 'procedure modular exponentiation' in your book was written specifically for b = 2 as it is indicated in 'n = (ak-1ak-2...a1a0)2' while it carries the subscript 'b' instead of 2 in 'procedure base expansion'.

Comment: OH MY GOSH! It took me a couple hours, but I actually figured out what's supposed to happen (ironically it was your last comment that made me figure it out). For the line `a = baseExp(n, b)` if we change it to `a = baseExp(n, 2)` it expands it into binary which is BASE 2 and works for the original pseudo-code! That's why the book wrote it that way!I have to DOUBLE thank you, I wouldn't have figured that out if it weren't for your observation!