# How to compute (A^B)%M when A,B,M are big numbers?

Tags: python, algorithm, python-3.x, math, exponentiation

For example, if `A = 864927518`, `B = 1462579282` ,`M = 193773611`, how to compute `(A^B)%M`?

Is there a simple way?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calculating pow(a,b) mod n](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8496182/calculating-powa-b-mod-n)

Comment: [Modular exponentiation implementation in Python 3](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18804958/995714), [How did Python implement the built-in function pow()?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10539256/995714)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes: use [modular exponentiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation). Python's built in [`pow`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#pow) function allows you to do this with its optional third argument:

```
>>> pow(A, B, M)
2767533
```

Answer (score 2):

```
3>> pow(864927518, 1462579282, 193773611)
2767533
```

Comment: How does it run so fast? It's near instantaneous

Comment: @TimCastelijns: By using a well-known equivalent equation.

Answer (score 1):

I shall blithely assume that you are using `^` as the exponentiation operator here (rather than as XOR). You can either use the built-in `pow` or you can code your own:

```
import math

def expmod(i, j, m):
  """Compute (i ** j) % m"""

  acc = 1
  mask = 2 ** int(math.ceil(math.log(j, 2)))
  while mask > 0:
    acc = acc * acc
    if mask & j:
      acc = acc * i
      j = j ^ mask
    mask = mask // 2
    acc = acc % m

  return acc
```